# How to define an Map having UUID key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary

I want to define a HashMap  using JPA . The key type of map  is UUID. I am using hibernate 3.6.So I have to use @Type annotation to define a column with UUID type.

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "mapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "map_id"))
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "intern_id")
@Column(name = "extern_id")
private Map<UUID, String> fetch = new ConcurrentHashMap<UUID, String>();
```

When I try to save , I am getting ClassCastException. What is way of doing this?

```
Error in saving project: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.UUIDTypeDescriptor.unwrap(UUIDTypeDescriptor.java:37) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:52) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:89) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:85) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:815) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1203) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795) [:3.6.0.Final]
at org.jboss.jpa.impl.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.flush(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:235) [:2.0.0]
at com.siemens.siguard.psa.server.importer.gdm.SincalImport.importData(SincalImport.java:48) [:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72) [:1.1.3]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76) [:1.1.3]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62) [:1.1.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_30]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_30]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_30]
at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74) [:1.1.3]
at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_5738454.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_5738454.java) [:]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90) [:1.1.3]
at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_5738454.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_5738454.java) [:]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.concurrency.aop.interceptor.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.invoke(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:181) [:1.0.0-alpha-4]
at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerInstanceInterceptor.invoke(PerInstanceInterceptor.java:86) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:247) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:349) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52) [:0.0.1]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76) [:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42) [:1.0.3]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67) [:1.0.1]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.ejb3.singleton.aop.impl.AOPBasedInterceptorRegistry.intercept(AOPBasedInterceptorRegistry.java:110) [:1.0.0-alpha-28]
at org.jboss.ejb3.singleton.impl.container.SingletonContainer.invoke(SingletonContainer.java:206) [:1.0.0-alpha-28]
at org.jboss.ejb3.singleton.aop.impl.AOPBasedSingletonContainer.dynamicInvoke(AOPBasedSingletonContainer.java:432) [:1.0.0-alpha-28]
at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53) [:1.7.17]
at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91) [jboss-aop.jar:2.2.1.GA]
at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82) [:1.0.1.GA]
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548) [:6.0.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234) [:6.0.0.Final]
```

Comment: what is the type of the intern_id column in your database? is it uiid-char?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `@Type` to `uuid-char` is not applicable in your code as the type of the field is `java.util.Map`, the definition for `@Type` annotation says:

> @org.hibernate.annotations.Type overrides the default hibernate type
>   used: this is generally not necessary since the type is correctly
>   inferred by Hibernate.

To fix the issue you have to use `@MapKeyType` :

> Allows defining the type of the key of a persistent map.

You can refer to [this link](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5507) to know the use of this annotation.

So your code should have below annotation instead of `@Type`

```
@MapKeyType(value=@Type(type="uuid-char"))
```

or

```
@MapKeyType(value=@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType"))
```

You can also refer to [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic) for the available UUID types.